# spring framework and webflux versions are incompatible

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, repository, spring-webflux

I have a old version spring-framework project. spring-framework version is `3.1.1.RELEASE`. I need import webflux but versions are incompatible, so if i add these code in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

not work because spring-webflux:3.1.1.RELEASE is not published in maven repo. How can i solve this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: You cannot (nor should) mix jars from different versions of a framework it won't work (incompatible) or lead to weird to debug issues. In short you cannot use a Spring 5 part with Spring 3 as those are incompatible. You will need to upgrade everything to Spring 5 (and as a consequence at least Java 8) and this will probably involve upgrading more dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

It was added in Spring 5. I am afraid you need to update to Spring 5.